# Nuxeo delete button

Tags: nuxeo

I'm looking to hide the "Delete" button on the view_documents only if the selected custom document have a boolean property to 1.

I'm using the Studio only ... I tried to implement a contribution to the extension point "filter" but it not seems to work.

Here is the condition I'm using in the contribution:

```
<extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.actions.ActionService" point="filters">
  <filter id="canDeleteScan">
    <rule grant="false">
      <condition>#{currentDocument.getProperty("SchemaDocument.scanner").equals("false")}</condition>
    </rule>
  </filter>
</extension>
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks